# Select and group rows in summary by hour

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, group-by

I have a table containing view/click records. The time is stored in a unix timestamp and I need to be able to pull out all of them within the specific month/day (based off of timestamps), but more importantly and the part I don't know how to do is group them by hour.  I need to be able to do this in a single query rather than looping through each hour.

Database is MySQL, language is PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select hour(somedate), count(*) from yourtable group by hour(somedate)
```

If you need all three:

```
select month(somedate), day(somedate), hour(somedate), count(*) from yourtable group by month(somedate), day(somedate), hour(somedate)
```

Comment: When I run the following query:

SELECT * , HOUR( TIMESTAMP ) AS HOUR 
FROM ad_view
LIMIT 0 , 30

It returns 838 as the hour, where it should be the number of hours in the current day.

Comment: Sorry, the number of hours into the current day (0-24) that the timestamp is.

Comment: are you sure that's really a timestamp? is it a timestamp integer stored in an int column or something?

Comment: hour() takes a time, not a unix timestamp.  You want to use hour(from_unixtime(somedate)).  Same for your other functions?

Comment: if it's a unix timestamp int rather than a column of type timestamp, keith may be right

Comment: You had it right, I used this:

[code]SELECT COUNT(id) as view_count, DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) as day FROM ad_view WHERE timestamp > '.$start.' AND timestamp < '.$end.' GROUP BY day[/code]