# query to group by datetime and total values of another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
"id, capture_date, data1, data2"
```

The capture_date field is a DATETIME field in mysql.
A script is run to capture some data (data1 INT and data2 INT)

Now I would like to total the data1 and data2 per hour.
So I need to group the capture_date field for the hour but total the data1 and data2 fields.

Any one knows how? Ive hardly worked with DATETIME field.
ps: The capture hasn't started yet, and I am still able to change the fieldtype if needed.

Comment: I was planning, before I saw rabbude's answer, to split the date and time field, time only saving the hour, which would allow me to group by the hour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select and group rows in summary by hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633293/select-and-group-rows-in-summary-by-hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform `DATETIME` field with `DATE_FORMAT` so you get the hours per day and group over this expression

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(capture_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') capture_date,SUM(data1) data1,SUM(data2) data FROM <table> GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(capture_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
```